# Create mouse_over event with Smarty?

Tags: php, css, smarty, onmouseover

I have a site that is almost all PHP files which make calls to TPL files. On the front page called index.php, there are images which are displayed according to variables from the TPL/PHP calls.

Usually I would just make onmouseclick do=etc, but there is no HTML anywhere, just TPL and PHP.

I want to create mouse_over events on the images on the main page. Is this possible without HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Templates are html files (with some pseudo-programming language) - it doesn't matter if it has html or tpl extension.
Find your HTML code in that tpl files and if there is something missing, it will be probably in the php files.

Comment: that sounds like the right plan. thanks, sorry if i wasted anyone's time.

Answer (score 0):

> there is no HTML anywhere, just TPL and PHP.
>
> I want to create mouse_over events on the images on the main page. Is
>   this possible without HTML?

Are you sure??? And what browser does display? Dosn't it HTML? Smarty (like any other template engine) is used only to sepate logic and view. All variable passed from PHP to Smarty (from *.php to *tpl) are rounded by HTML-code. You could use in Smarty any HTMl-code. It could be link(don't any link on your site?), paragraphs, spans, div(don't you have any text-structure on your site). You should use html to display content. And you could use javascript in your templates. It is not forbitten. Looks like you have missed something. 
[http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=javascript+in+smarty+templates&oq=javascript+in+smarty+templates&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=11544l17461l0l17646l21l20l0l13l13l0l249l1210l1.3.3l7l0&biw=1272&bih=859&cad=h](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=javascript%20in%20smarty%20templates&oq=javascript%20in%20smarty%20templates&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=11544l17461l0l17646l21l20l0l13l13l0l249l1210l1.3.3l7l0&biw=1272&bih=859&cad=h)

Comment: Basically I'm just trying to find where the code is for these images to make a rollover. But there is just a mess of Javascript, PHP, CSS and TPL files. When you view the page on a browser, the pages appear as index.php.html. But, in reality there is no index.html on the site. It's all PHP variables passed to TPL and back. I'm not a moron, I'm just used to being able to find the code that creates controls. somebody else designed this weird site in India like 5 years ago